# I changed my username but my YouTube channel title shows my old name

Tags: youtube

I changed my YouTube name using the "Edit on Google" link in the "Overview" section in YouTube.

This worked fine and I see the new name but when I got to my channel page it still shows the old name for the channel title. Is there a separate setting to update my channel title?

It also shows my old name in a few other sections like "Analytics" in "Creator Studio".

Here is a screenshot to show you the problem. My new name appears correctly in the account popup view but on my channel page it still shows the old name in the title.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can take a while until the name change is displayed everywhere. Clearing your cache and cookies may speed it up for you, but if you just wait, it should change itself *eventually*.

Note that your old name will persist longest in search results, sometimes for weeks.

Comment: Ok, I changed it weeks ago and it's still like that. I tried clearing cache and cookies but no luck. The new name appear correctly in search results but it still shows the old name on the video pages and in my channel title.

Comment: Yes, it finally changed. It took a couple months.

Comment: the same for a channel I own. It's not acceptable in 2019 to wait MONTHS to get a  name: updated!

Answer (score 1):

### Reason why you name is not changing:

- As others said, it might just be because you haven't waited long enough (for me, it took multiple weeks)
- It could be possible that you are using a Brand Account. If you're using a Brand Account, you have to change it in by going into YouTube and clicking on the `Settings` option in the menu bar. Then click on `Edit on Google` which is located next to your profile picture.

Comment: the "edit on google" was made but everywhere it's changed except on the video channel. Adn I cannot publishing videos under the old name.

Comment: @TormyVanCool are you sure you are not using a brand account for your channel? Just search on Google about YouTube brand accounts.

Comment: I was cosntrained to open a channel, FROM the account, in order to get what I needed and immediately. Otherwise there was not any hope

Answer (score 0):

For me, for whatever reason, it only changed when I did it both on the app on my phone and on my computer. Idk why, but there you go; it was immediate. 
Still takes forever to do the same in the search, though.

Answer (score 0):

Idk if it was accident or not, but my solution seemed to work. I had the same problem to where it showed my old name, so I had an idea. I changed my name again (naming it the same thing) and it replaced my old name with my new name, since I changed it twice. (If it doesn't work, trying using 2 devices.)

Ex:
Old name: "Potato".
New name: "Chip".
Change name again to: "Chip".
YouTube thinks “Chip” was your old name.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled for a few days, changing and re-changing... I changed in my google profile but it didn't work... THIS WORKED.. dunno why.

YouTube > 
My Channel > 
Settings (on left menu) > 
Account Settings [click "View or change your account settings"] .... NOT "Edit on Google" >
Personal Info >
Name >  ... enter change name.